# $L^p(\mu)$ vs $L^p(dP)$

Tags: analysis

I'm reading J. Michael Steele's [Stochastic Calculus and Financial Applications](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781441928627), and a bit confused at a notation comment on $L^p$ space:

At Appendix I *Mathematical Tools*, it says

> **Notational Matters**
>
> The notation that one uses to describe function spaces has natural
> variation,  though less than one finds in urban pigeons. For example,
> $L^P$ always denotes a set  of functions for which the absolute $p$'th
> power is integrable, but there are many  different measure spaces
> where these functions may live, and the plumage adorning  $L^p(\mu)$
> or $L^p(dP)$ just reflects this variation.

I'm a bit confused here: what is difference between them? is it that $L^p(\mu)$ are spaces on discrete probability while $L^p(dP)$ are on continuous probability?

Comment: $\mu$ and $P$ are just different (names of) measures. Both could be discrete or absolutely continuous with right to the corresponding Lesbegue measure.

Comment: @unwissen reading the lines of the book I assume conventionally there's a difference between $L^p(\mu)$ and $L^p(dP)$.

Comment: $L^{p}(dP)$ is same as $L^{p}(P)$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy so is it also same as $L^p(\mu)$?

Comment: Only if $\mu =P$.